# How to call javascript function in cocos2d-js

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

How can I call javascript function in cocos2d-js.

I need to call `split` method.

If I call `"This is a sample string".split(/ /g)` it works fine. But I need to call it on a cocos2d object.

I believe somehow I need to convert cocos2d-js variable(string) to javascript executable object.

Please help.

Comment: Could you post some code where you're trying to use `split` and it doesn't work?

Comment: I just found the solution. I was calling it incorrectly. It is working fine. Sorry for the trouble.